# Image Slider JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I write this code but next button is not working it shows error Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

```
<script language="javascript" >
    var pics=new Array("img1.jpeg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg","img5.jpg");
    var count=0; var len=pics.length;
    function next() {
        // body...
        count++;
        if (count<len) {
            document.pic.src=pics[count];
        }
        else{
            count=0;
            document.pic.src=pics[count];
        }
    }
    function changePic(imgSrc) {
    document.getElementById("pic").src=imgSrc;

}
</script>
```

When i Click Next button it will show next image from the Slide bar

Answer (score 0):

1. Do with `document.getElementById("pic")` instead of `document.pic` .`document.id` to target the element is not a good practise

OR use **`changePic(pics[count])`**

```
var pics=new Array("img1.jpeg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg","img5.jpg");
    var count=0; var len=pics.length;
    function next() {
        // body...
        count++;
        if (count<len) {
            document.getElementById("pic").src=pics[count];
            //OR
            changePic(pics[count]);
        }
        else{
            count=0;
            document.getElementById("pic").src=pics[count];
            //OR
             changePic(pics[count]);
        }
    }
    function changePic(imgSrc) {
      document.getElementById("pic").src=imgSrc;
    }
```